# C# ActiveDirectory, how to add range to filter

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm basically trying to filter my results using DirectorySearcher to a range of members, however this filter returns no results.

> "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=Users,OU=myou,OU=base,OU=home,DC=gorge,DC=net)(member;range=0-1499))"

```
DirectoryEntry dEntryhighlevel = 
          new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=base,OU=home,DC=gorge,DC=net");
DirectorySearcher dSeacher = 
          new DirectorySearcher(dEntryhighlevel);
dSeacher.Filter = 
        "(&(objectClass=user)
         (memberof=CN=Users,OU=myou,OU=base,OU=home,DC=gorge,DC=net)
         ("+attributeWithRange+"))";
dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attributeWithRange);
dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
dSeacher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
dSeacher.PageSize = 1500;
SearchResultCollection resultCollection = resultCollection = dSeacher.FindAll();
```

This code works just fine without the range filter.  Any help here would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be that you're trying to insert the range into the `Filter` *as well as* into the `PropertiesToLoad`. If you take a look at the first [code example on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180907%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you can see that the range is being added only to the `PropertiesToLoad` for the instance of the `DirectorySearcher` class.